# how to redirect all the not found pages in to a common page using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used a URL rewriting in my php web site. I need to redirect all the not found page to a coming soon page

See my code in `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=permanent,QSA]  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA] 

    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/commingSoon.php
```

But when i browse an invalid page its results in

```
Not Found

The requested URL /komet-india/Houseboat.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Is my code in hatches is wrong?

Please help me

Comment: Can you access that error page directly? Is there really a correct redirect happening?

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using a lot of code.It can be done with these three lines

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ comingsoonpage.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the 404 html page in apache to a custom one?

1. Create a Web page that will be your 404 document.
2. Open yourhttpd.conffile for editing (you'll probably have to login as root to edit it).
3. Find the line that reads

   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
4. Change the third entry to the URI you would like to display, e.g.

   ErrorDocument 404 /new_404.html
5. Restart your Web server.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/apache/ht/ht404apache.htm